# How to reduce the 'useEffect` hook to make more performance

Tags: react.js, typescript

I have created a `tab` Accordion. at present it works fine. it should:

1. open and close on click ( shuffling )
2. on click of a tab other tabs should be closed if open already.

for this, I used 2 `userEffect` hook and a function to handle my click event. it is utilizing the `provider` from context as well. I am little bit confused about my approach considering performace.

please some one review the code and give the advice if I am wrong?

here is my code and demo:

```
  import React, {
  createContext,
  ReactNode,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export interface ContextProps {
  isExpand: number | null;
  childHandler: (v: number) => void;
}

export const initialContextProps: ContextProps = {
  isExpand: null,
  childHandler(v: number) {}
};

export const parentContext = createContext<ContextProps>(initialContextProps);
const { Provider } = parentContext;

function Children({ label, si }: { label: string; si: number }): JSX.Element {
  const { isExpand, childHandler } = useContext(parentContext);
  const [classProps, setClassProps] = useState(false);
  useEffect(
    function () {
      if (si === isExpand) {
        setClassProps(true);
      }
    },
    [setClassProps, si, isExpand]
  );

  useEffect(
    function () {
      if (si !== isExpand) {
        setClassProps(false);
      }
    },
    [setClassProps, si, isExpand]
  );

  function setClass(index: number) {
    setClassProps((prev) => !prev);
    childHandler(index);
  }

  return (
    <li onClick={() => setClass(si)} className={classProps ? "expand" : ""}>
      {label} :: {si} || {isExpand} -- {classProps}
      {classProps && <div>Content</div>}
    </li>
  );
}

function Parent({ children }: { children: ReactNode }): JSX.Element {
  const [isExpand, setIsExpand] = useState<number | null>(0);
  function childHandler(si: number) {
    setIsExpand(si);
  }
  return (
    <Provider value={{ isExpand, childHandler }}>
      <ul>{children} </ul>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent>
        <Children key={1} label="Title-1" si={0} />
        <Children key={2} label="Title-2" si={1} />
        <Children key={3} label="Title-3" si={2} />
        <Children key={4} label="Title-4" si={3} />
        <Children key={5} label="Title-5" si={4} />
      </Parent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[LIVE-DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-component-with-call-back-jmtjv7?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

Nice job having it worked! However a few improvements can be done:

**Comments about coding conventions:**

- Please name your variables, functions, parameters properly, so that it's easier for other people to review your code. For example, `si` and `index` refer to the same thing, you should keep the naming consistent throughout your work. Another example is, `Parent`, `Children`, `childHandler` sound confusing, please rename them into the actual thing you are making, like `Accordion`, `AccodionItem`, `onOpen`, etc.
- You can upload your snippet onto github, so that reviewers can easily target at specific lines and point out the exact problem.

**Problems about your code:**

Basically your code is an overkill to what you wanna acheive.

- Use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) only on something that doesn't change often, because

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes.

- You defined a boolean state under each child, which is unnecessary if you are already using Context. The `expand` state can be directly determined by `si === isExpand`
- Two `useEffect` callbacks have the exact same dependencies, you can combine them into one, but again, you do not need them.

**A better solution:**

Think about the data structure of your components. It can be an array contains a number of objects, with each has properties `id`, `label` and `isOpen`. Make that your state and use `.map` to render them. In that way, React compares the props passed into your component and skip re-rendering if the props remain the same, so it's more performant in that way.

Comment: can you update my code as your wish? and post it?

Comment: Another suggestion - you should always put into your efforts first then ask for help. I can help make edits to your update. If you need a bit of hint - you can search for to-do list implementation in React on internet, it incorporates the same idea as I mentioned in the solution